# AWS S3 pre-signed URL behaving differently for different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

We have AWS python lambdas deployed on us-east-1, for one of the functionality we generate pre-signed URL from lambda send to frontend and from their
we directly upload the file to S3. This is working fine for us-east-1.
We recently deployed same code to us-east-2, their this functionality is not working. it is generating pre-signed URL but when frontend tries to upload file to S3 it is giving 403 access denied.
I found that there are different version of algorithm used by boto3 s3 client to generate the pre-signed URL.
I logged pre-signed algorithm version in both region it is using v4.

I noticed one different in PUT request to S3 from frontend:

```
1. for us-east-1 it is sending this parameters:
    Expires=1702627703
    
2. for us-east-2 it is sending this:
    X-Amz-Date=20231215T101608Z&
    X-Amz-Expires=36000&
    X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
```

For us-east-2 it is using v4(X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 indicates that) but i dont think for us-east-1 it is using v4 even though it is printing v4 in logs.
How can i fix this issue?

Edit:
I have found the issue. issue is in Metadata, when i removed the Metadata from pre-signed URL then it worked. Here is the code:

```
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='put_object',
    ExpiresIn=3600,
    Params={
        'Bucket': "user-uploads",
            'Key': "124-456",
            'ContentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Metadata': {
                'key1': '123-456',
                'key2': '123-456',
                'user_name': 'user@example.com',
                'user_id': 'jon_doe'
            }
    }
)
```

Why removing Metadata works for us-east-2 but same code is working for us-east-1?

Comment: Is the X-Amz-Date value shown (20231215) the actual value being sent today? When was the pre-signed URL calculated?

Comment: @jarmod X-Amz-Date date is of when debug the issue, it is correct. Is it not working because of clock synchronization issue?

Comment: Clock skew is certainly one possible issue though I'm not sure it would result in AccessDenied. Plus you indicated that one region works OK, so it's not likely to be that. But correct the clock anyhow. You need to double-check that the IAM permissions allow access to the object and that the bucket policy does not deny access.

Comment: @jarmod We're sending pre-signed url to client, so i dont think there is any IAM policy issue. Its working on east-1 because there it is sending when url is going to expire(in timestamp) but on east-2 its sending date(when url generated) and expires(seconds). Same code is generating different url on different env. east-2 code is using version 4 for url generation and east-1 is using v2(not sure), even though code is same.

Comment: Did you override the default behavior to force signature v4, as shown in the answer below?

Comment: @jarmod No, I did not override anything.

Comment: FYI if the pre-signed URL does not contain `X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` then it's not signature v4.

Comment: @jarmod Yes i know, even though in logs it show v4 internally it is using v2 i think, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Botocore uses signature version s3v2 while generating presigned post for us-east-1 region and uses s3v4 for the other regions

You can specify the signature version in your Boto Core S3 client

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', 'us-east-1', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```

Comment: For us-east-1 it is working fine. Code on us-east-2 is already using v4.

Comment: When you are hand-shaking resources internally in the same region X-Amz-Algorithm check is not required to validate the resource access policy but is required when 2 different regions are involved.

You can update your Lambda code to include signature version config in s3 client

Comment: anyway it is using v4, I don't think I need you override the signature version. I confirmed the version by logging, It is using v4 in both regions.